# spring boot application deployed as war on weblogic- not working

Tags: maven, spring-boot, weblogic

i am new to weblogic, struggling to deploy war. I have a spring boot application running on embedded tomcat.I changed main class as  follows.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.fmc.*")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationBoot extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 SpringApplication.run(
            ApplicationBoot.class, args);

}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
        SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ApplicationBoot.class);
}
```

}

i changed packaging as war and excluded the tomcat jars and deployed. But when a submit request, I am getting 404.
I don't see anything in logs in the diagnostics in admin console. Is there aythere place to see the logs. In the weblogic admin console,I can see the application as active and health as ok.

I changed the same application spring web application, it's running successfully, but not spring boot application.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ApplicationBoot extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
```

main class has to implement WebApplicationInitializer, thought of useful for some one